# Generate ctags for QML

Tags: ctags

Is it possible to generate ctags for QML? Except for writing the parser by my own? It is not in the list of supported languages on http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ but I still hope there is a chance to avoid writing my own parser.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think this question is not about Vim but about the utility ctags (or its equivalent) thus your question would be more appropriate for a site like the original [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/) or maybe [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `ctags` support for external languages not included on default parsing config.

[docs: extending ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/EXTENDING.html)

By using `--langdef=QML` and then creating a regex to help define the types of patterns `ctags` will parse as tags.

```
--langdef=QML
--langmap=QML:.QML,.qml
--regex-QML=/^qml tag definitions/
```

This extra config info needs to be stored in your home directory in file named `.ctags`. (I don't know the Windows locations for this.)